# Laptop goes through NTFS disk repair most boots, how to check SSD health?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, ntfs

This windows 10 laptop has an SSD and has been in service for about 5 years.

How do I check how healthy the SSD is?  Crystaldiskinfo doesn't show anything that jumps out at me (I am also not an expert at all the details in crystaldiskinfo)

What would a next step be?

[image]

Comment: Did this start recently? How do you turn the computer off? (i.e: Start -> Shutdown, or press and hold power button?)

Comment: @Attie I always go through the proper Windows Shutdown. And yes, this started recently.

Comment: May be Windows powers off the PC too early for the SSD? It is just the question if the SSD has changed (something got slower) or Windows changed it's behavior by an system update or a driver update (less time between shutdown and power off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual, real world answer is: Those NTFS disk checks were a precursor to... blue screens and system freezes.

Ultimately, the system became unusable (blue screening or freezing after 30-60 minutes of use).

The resolution was: Replace the SSD.

IOW: NTFS disk checks were an early sign of a failing SSD (whatever crystal disk info says).

Recovery method:

- System is a 2016 Dell XPS13 laptop
- Purchased a copy of Acronis True Image
- Booted up laptop, turned off Bitlocker (you can't image a bitlocked drive)
- Created a bootable USB stick of True Image
- Bought a new SSD for the laptop (NVMe M2 for this XPS13) and an external 1TB, USB-3 drive
- Booted laptop from USB stick
- Imaged the whole drive to the external 1TB drive
- Opened laptop, swapped in new SSD
- Booted from USB stick
- Restored image from external 1TB drive to internal SSD
- Booted up
- Used system heavily for 2 days
- Consider the issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Your SSD from the information look healthy. CrystalDiskInfo runs SMART test on your SSD (If your hard drive/SSD does not support it then result is Unknown), and the below details are different attributes of SMART. You can get a good overview on SMART attributes in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes).